# Camel endpoint creation failure during Karaf startup

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I am using Apache Karaf 2.3.1 and Apache Camel 2.10.4. Off the bat, I would like to state that I am not in a position to change the version of either product.

I have a number of bundles deployed in Karaf, and everything is working fine. But once in a while I get the following exception when Karaf starts up:

```
13:11:02,728 | ERROR | ExtenderThread-4 | BundleApplicationContextListener   50 | 68 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=camel-context.xml, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml)) org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException:
**org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route bosService: Route[[From[cxf:bean:MyServiceEndpoint]] -> [Bean[ref:JAXBF... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:MyServiceEndpoint due to: No component found with scheme: cxf**    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1316)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]     at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120)[222:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.10.4]     at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:280)[222:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.10.4]   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)[63:org.springframework.context:3.1.4.RELEASE]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:327)[63:org.springframework.context:3.1.4.RELEASE]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941)[63:org.springframework.context:3.1.4.RELEASE]  at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.java:235)[67:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]   at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:358)[67:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]   at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[67:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)[67:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]     at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)[68:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)[:1.7.0_25]
**Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route bosService: Route[[From[cxf:bean:MyServiceEndpoint]] -> [Bean[ref:JAXBF... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:MyServiceEndpoint due to: No component found with scheme: cxf**     at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:177)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]   at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:722)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]   at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1789)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]   at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1575)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1444)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]     at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.doStart(SpringCamelContext.java:179)[222:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.10.4]    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1412)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]   at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:228)[222:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.10.4]     at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:118)[222:org.apache.camel.camel-spring:2.10.4]     ... 10 more
**Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://bean:MyServiceEndpoint due to: No component found with scheme: cxf**    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:485)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]  at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:50)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:187)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]     at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:108)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:114)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]  at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:72)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:90)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]   at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:857)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]   at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:172)[176:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.10.4]
```

here is my **camel-context.xml**:

```
<beans:beans
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:camel-cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xmlns:httpj="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf
                             http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf-2.15.2-spring.xsd
                           http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration
                             http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd
                           http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
                             http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi  
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
                             http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.10.4.xsd">
    <osgi:reference id="MyService"      
                     interface="com.foo.blah.camel.MyService"/>

    <beans:bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus"/>

    <httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
        <httpj:engine port="8888">
            <httpj:sessionSupport>true</httpj:sessionSupport>
        </httpj:engine>
    </httpj:engine-factory>

    <camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint id="MyServiceEndpoint"
                     serviceClass="com.foo.blah.service.MyWebService"
                     address="http://0.0.0.0:8888/MyWebService">
        <camel-cxf:inInterceptors>
            <beans:bean class="com.foo.blah.camel.SomeInInterceptor"/>
        </camel-cxf:inInterceptors>
        <camel-cxf:outInterceptors>
            <beans:bean class="com.foo.blah.camel.SomeOutInterceptor"/>
        </camel-cxf:outInterceptors>
    </camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint>

    <camelContext id="my-camel-ctx" 
                xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
        <route id="MyRoute">
            <from uri="cxf:bean:MyServiceEndpoint"/>
            <bean id="myService" ref="MyService"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans:bean>
```

Because this problem is intermittent, I compared successful log with the one that contains the aforementioned stack. And while most of the content was identical, I did notice the following distinct differences:

**Successful log excerpt:**

> 11:23:00,072 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   BundleTypeConverterLoader$Loader  353 | 175 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Found 2 @Converter classes to
>   load 11:23:00,104 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   BundleTypeConverterLoader$Loader  353 | 175 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Found 2 @Converter classes to
>   load 11:23:00,104 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   BundleTypeConverterLoader$Loader  353 | 175 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Found 0 @Converter classes to
>   load 11:23:00,119 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   BundleTypeConverterLoader$Loader  353 | 175 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Found 2 @Converter classes to
>   load 11:23:00,150 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   BundleTypeConverterLoader$Loader  353 | 175 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Found 1 @Converter classes to
>   load 11:23:00,150 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   BundleTypeConverterLoader$Loader  353 | 175 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Found 1 @Converter classes to
>   load 11:23:00,166 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   BundleTypeConverterLoader$Loader  353 | 175 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Found 1 @Converter classes to
>   load 11:23:00,229 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   e.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext 1398 | 175 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Apache Camel 2.10.4
>   (CamelContext: my-camel-ctx) is starting

**Failed log excerpt:**

> 13:11:02,587 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   e.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext 1398 | 176 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Apache Camel 2.10.4
>   (CamelContext: my-camel-ctx) is starting 13:11:02,587 | INFO  |
>   ExtenderThread-4 | e.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext 1464 | 176 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Tracing is enabled on
>   CamelContext: my-camel-ctx 13:11:02,712 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4 |
>   e.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext 1590 | 176 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | **Apache Camel 2.10.4
>   (CamelContext: my-camel-ctx) is shutting down** 13:11:02,712 | INFO  |
>   ExtenderThread-4 | verter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry  522 | 176 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | TypeConverterRegistry
>   utilization[attempts=5, hits=4, **misses=1**, failures=0]
>   mappings[total=172, **misses=1**] 13:11:02,728 | INFO  | ExtenderThread-4
>   | e.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext 1656 | 176 -
>   org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.10.4 | Apache Camel 2.10.4
>   (CamelContext: my-camel-ctx) is shutdown in 0.000 seconds. Uptime
>   0.141 seconds.

As you can see, Camel shuts down almost immediately after starting up, which I am guessing is what leads to the exception at hand. Furthermore, it does not list the @Converter classes as denoted in the successful log, but instead denotes that there is one miss. I am not sure if that has anything to do with the shutdown, but here is what I found at http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html:

> Returning null values By default when using a method in a POJO
>   annotation with @Converter returning null is not a valid response. If
>   null is returned, then Camel will regard that type converter as a
>   miss, and prevent from using it in the future. If null should be
>   allowed as a valid response, then from Camel 2.11.2/2.12 onwards you
>   can specify this in the annotation as shown:

```
@Converter(allowNull = true) 
public static InputStream toInputStream(File file) throws
 IOException {
     if (file.exist()) {
         return new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
     } else {
         return null;
     } 
}
```

I do not have any @Coverter instances in my code, so this must be complaining about ones that are within the libraries being references by my application. I have looked everywhere for a solution, but without success. So any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Check if your bundle start level is greater than the cxf and camel bundles start level.

Comment: @JérémieB good point, as that was one of my first checks. all my bundles start levels are later than the 3rd party bundles they reference.